# How to find index organized table

Tags: oracle, index

I'm working on Oracle 11g database and I need to list all index-organized tables.
Is there a dba's view to query for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the query you require:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM DBA_TABLES
WHERE IOT_TYPE IS NOT NULL;
```

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#i1592091) states:

> If this is an index-organized table, then IOT_TYPE is IOT,
>   IOT_OVERFLOW, or IOT_MAPPING. If this is not an index-organized table,
>   then IOT_TYPE is NULL.

Answer (score 6):

If you lack DBA access (and responsibility for tables you lack access to) Query [ALL_TABLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2105.htm#i1592091) checking if IOT_TYPE is not null, otherwise query [DBA_TABLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5051.htm#REFRN23286) where IOT_TYPE is not null.

```
Select table_name FROM ALL_TABLES where IOT_TYPE is not null

Select table_name FROM DBA_TABLES where IOT_TYPE is not null
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables WHERE iot_type IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: How is your answer different than others?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT table_name FROM dba_tables WHERE iot_type IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: How is your answer different than others?